# Access S3 event notification from within python in a Lambda container

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, dockerfile

As a cloud developer, I am currently working on a AWS architecture which include both AWS S3 and Lambda services.

*My goal here is to be able to catch the S3 notification event from  a python function in a Lambda container.*

The workflow is the following :

1. A file is dropped in a `bucket-A`
2. It triggers a Lambda built with a container image stored in ECR (AWS container registry)

Typically, for a classic lambda function, what you define as your handler must be prototyped as `def lambda_handler(event, context);` to properly receive the S3 event notification.

In the example found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-image.html), we can see that using

```
# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

where `app` is the filename (app.py) and `handler` the function within this file can allow us to reach the code.
**Note: app.py is in the working directory defined by `WORKDIR` from Dockerfile.**

### Directory Structure (EDIT)

The `route_serializer.py` is the python file that needs to be reached from the Dockerfile. It contains a function called lambda_handler that will handle the S3 notifications and process the newly arrived file.
This is the exact structure present within the container when running the Lambda.

```
project/
├── aws/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── lambdas/
│   │   ├── batchDisaggregator/
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   └── route_serializer.py <-- contains lambda_handler(evt,ctx);
│   │   └── __init__.py
```

### What I tried

- Setting `__init__.py` in the nested folders to route_serializer to make it available to python executable.
- add `path/to/pythonfile` in PATH env variable.

So I would like to know if there's a way I can call the handler function (`def lambda_handler(event, context);`) from the `CMD` override available in Lambda, and catch the S3 notification within the event function argument.

Comment: @deadshot sorry if I wasn't clear but that is the case. My Lambda is triggered by the S3 event (`ObjectCreated:Put`).  When it does so, I have the possibility to override 3 arguments from the Dockerfile used to generate this container : CMD, WORKDIR and ENTRYPOINT. My question is how to write the CMD (or a combination of several commands) in order to be able to call a python function within a nested python file inside the container.

Comment: why nested python file? what is your usecase exactly?

Comment: nested means that it is not at the root of the container defined in Dockerfile. Even when defining the WORKDIR to the path of the file I want to run i'm still getting the error `\"route_serializer.lambda_handler\": executable file not found in $PATH"`. My usecase is the simplest ever, catch the S3 notification from within a Lambda container. I can't really see how can I simplify it more ?

Comment: why don't you call the required python file/function in `app.handler`

Comment: @RnneMsly can you update the question with your folder structure and modify the question to explain it.

Comment: @RnneMsly also make sure you added the files to your dockerfile steps.

Comment: **UPDATE** : I was missing the LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT env variable that defines where to store your handler. still working on it

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out by myself. For everyone with the same issues, here's some leads that might help you aswell

In my case, I was missing 2 things :

- My custom-based image used to run the container had the [awslambdaric](https://pypi.org/project/awslambdaric/) package to make it compliant with lambda. But I needed to run my function with the following `CMD` : `/path/to/python -m awslambdaric batchDisaggregator.route_serializer` to allow the runtime interface to call my function.
- Function code and all the dependecies should be stored under the path specified in the `LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT` environment variable. You can define it within the Dockerfile using `ENV LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT=/var/task`

Feel free to comment if you need more information about how I solved this